# Ive tried Everything to fix my BSOD can anyone help? (BSOD Critical_Process_Died)

Tags: windows-10, bsod

Too start off, Ill give some context. I was just using my computer (Omen Gaming Laptop) and Over the last couple days, I noticed it started to slow down, I couldn't open more than two tabs without chrome completely crashing.

This was when I noticed that my Memory was slowly being taken up, It got so bad I even had to delete all of my games that took up too much space. I had also recently gotten a new hard drive because my other one had fried, this one only came with 238GB of C: storage. **(Note that my computer heats up very quickly due to only having two fans, I use a Laptop and neither fans cool off the middle of the computer)** I started messing with some files, deleting things I was told were useless Etc. If I didn't know what a file was I wouldn't touch it. **Another note, I was on discord and had scrolled past an image which activated my antivirus**

Now for the actual problem, Which is that I have a unfix-able BSOD along with every problem a computer can possibly have, And I don't think I can fix it. Here's a list of things I've tried to fix it:

Every CMD prompt I could find, The result is usually an error message saying I don't have access

I've tried restore points, which just says "Access denied" and then gives an error code which means I have a write protected disk.

Ive tried both system Reset options which says that "There was a problem with resetting this PC"

Safe mode doesn't work, just gives me a BSOD

Startup Repair doesn't work, and trying to use it puts me in a loop of restarting and going back to the BSOD

**Ive also noticed I no longer have admin permissions** which could mean that a hacker of some sort took them away or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED

It seems I had too much space taken up to much space to start up my computer, If your having the same problem follow these instructions

Open CMD prompt from the F11 Troubleshoot settings.

Run the CMD Diskpart

Run Disk List

Type Select disk #

then type Clear

type EXIT

Done.

this will wipe your computer, and you will have to download windows 10 again. also when i said "Type Select disk #" the # is reference to whichever disk you are using.

Comment: That's not exactly a good solution for everyone, loosing everything.

Comment: `I had too much space taken up to much space` .. ??